# FTP - File name not allowed. (REMOTE SERVER ERROR 533) C#

Tags: c#, xml, request, ftp

My app is simple:

> Getting list of files from ftp - step 1
>
> Looping each of items and getting file - step 2
>
> Writing content from a xml file to database - step 3
>
> Before moving to another item in loop let's move processed file to
>   another folder - step 4 (error)

Here's my code (please read comments!) :

```
if (ftpFiles.Any())
{
    foreach (var file in ftpFiles)
    {
        try
        {
            var item_path = $"ftp://my.url.ok:somePort/{item.FtpFolderName}/in/" + file;
            FtpWebRequest xml_request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(item_path);
            xml_request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
            xml_request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

            using (FtpWebResponse xml_response = (FtpWebResponse)xml_request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader xml_reader = new StreamReader(xml_response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    // PROCESSING XML FILE AND MAKING DATABASE CALL TO INSERT VALUE TO DB AND THAT IS FINE!
                }
            }


            // BEFORE I MOVE TO ANOTHER FILE IN LOOP I WANT TO MOVE PREVIOUS FILE TO ANOTHER FOLDER

            var item_to_move_original_path = $"ftp://my.url.ok:somePort/{item.FtpFolderName}/in/" + file;
            var item_to_move_new_path = $"ftp://my.url.ok:somePort/{item.FtpFolderName}/processed/" + file;

            FtpWebRequest xml_request_rename = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(item_to_move_original_path);    
            xml_request_rename.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.Rename;

            xml_request_rename.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
            xml_request_rename.RenameTo = item_to_move_new_path;

            // IN LINE BELOW APP CRASHES AND IT SAYS THAT File name is not allowed

            // One more question here is can I use xml_request that I've created in a loop earlier to rename/move a file or I have to crate this
            // xml_request_rename
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)xml_request_rename.GetResponse();

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to upload a file to that location using an existing FTP client like Filezilla?

Comment: @C.Evenhuis Yes. I'm using FileZilla and I could write to that location without any issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to solve this by changing this url (***removing part of the url***):

```
var item_to_move_new_path = $"ftp://my.url.ok:somePort/{item.FtpFolderName}/processed/" + file;
```

to:

```
var item_to_move_new_path = $"/{item.FtpFolderName}/processed/" + file;
```

As it's possible to notice I've removed an

```
ftp://my.url.ok:somePort/
```

from path, and everything worked, how come???

Everything works but I don't know why, if anyone could explain this to me and to other ppl who are watching this thead that would be awesome!